# Legend using Pound "#" plus pch 15

Tags: r

Stuck getting my simple legend to print the proper symbols, the first needs to be a square which is pch 15, the second needs to be "#"

[square] y=x^2 
[hashtag] y=1-x^2

```
legend("topright", legend=c("y=x^2", "y=1-x^2"),
       col=c("red", "blue"),cex=1,pch=c(15,"#"))
```

Now what is happening the legend sees 1 then 5 where it should be a square & the hashtag, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach would be to repeat the `legend` two times while changing one of them to missing value (`NA`)

```
plot(1, 1)
sapply(list(c(15, NA), c(NA, "#")), function(x) 
   legend("topright", legend = c("y=x^2", "y=1-x^2"),
             col=c("red", "blue"),cex=1, pch = x))
```

[image]